# Python PyQT5 webview mixes url when plugin required

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtwebengine

I load a url successfully in my web view but when a plugin is required the source url is mixing ,as a result mixed content error arrives even if the later url is https.

The exact error is :

```
js: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://ww1.jeppesen.com/icharts/index.jsp' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/index.html?https://ww1.jeppesen.com/icharts/pdfchart%3Fdocid%3D1134104263'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

Because site needs account  i provide and picture:

[image]

my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineSettings
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *



class MyTest(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTest, self).__init__(parent)

    # def createWindow(self,wintype):
        # self.webView = MyTest()
        # self.webView.show()

        # return super(MyTest, self).createWindow(wintype)


class Ui_Dialog19(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog19,var_user,var_pass):
        Dialog19.setObjectName("Dialog19")
        Dialog19.resize(800, 600)
        Dialog19.setWindowFlags(Dialog19.windowFlags() |
        QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint |
        QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint)
        self.var_user = var_user
        self.var_pass = var_pass
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Dialog19)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.webView = MyTest(self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.webView, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Dialog19)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        self.setLayout(self.gridLayout)


        self.webView.installEventFilter(self)
        self.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("https://ww1.jeppesen.com/icharts/"))
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog19)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog19)






        self.webView.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)


    def showEvent(self,event):
        # self.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("https://ww1.jeppesen.com/icharts/"))
        pass

    def _on_load_finished(self):
        self.webView.page().toHtml(self.Callable)

        # self.webView.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.AllowRunningInsecureContent, True)

    def Callable(self, html_str):
        self.html = html_str


        self.webView.page().runJavaScript("document.getElementsByName('login-username')[0].value='%s';"%(self.var_user))
        self.webView.page().runJavaScript("document.getElementsByName('login-password')[0].value='%s';"%(self.var_pass))
        self.webView.page().runJavaScript("document.getElementById('loginSubmit').click();")
        self.webView.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)
        self.webView.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.JavascriptCanOpenWindows, True)
        self.webView.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, True)
        self.webView.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.HyperlinkAuditingEnabled, True)
        self.webView.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
        self.webView.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.AllowWindowActivationFromJavaScript, True)
        self.webView.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.FullScreenSupportEnabled, True)
        self.webView.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.JavascriptCanPaste, True)
        self.webView.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, True)




    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog19):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog19.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog19", "Eva air insider"))
```

Comment: It is difficult to help you if you do not provide a [MRE], in your case as you indicate authentication is required and as we do not have the credentials then it complicates it, analyze how the MRE provides

Comment: can i ignore this error via javaScriptConsoleMessage?certificateError dont catch this

Comment: What is your question?, What is your main objective? Do you just want the messages not printed on the console?

Comment: No but i cant get why this error occures only when plug in is required and the src is https, can i text you the credentials for the site privatelly?

Comment: You still don't answer what your question is, you point out in your post that you have that error message and nothing else. Do you only get that error in QWebEngineView or do you also get it in google-chome, firefox, etc?

Comment: all the contents in site is https(safe) but when site requests a plugin (which i have enabled)the plugin name is in front of src url (see image red circle and error) and web view dont recognize it as safe as https is after plugin name.The site is running fine in chrome.I just illustrate this site in my webview app.

Comment: You still don't answer me. What is your question? Do you want to know why this happens? o Do you just want to hide the error message?

Comment: I want to fix it cause then frame dont saw in my web view

Comment: I think you should point that out explicitly in your question since, as your publication points out, it can be interpreted in many ways. On the other hand send me your credentials to e.yllanescucho@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198672/discussion-between---and-eyllanesc).